# Build error with first Android Emulator software

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, build-error

I'm getting this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   MSB3073 The command "gradlew.bat -p "C:\Users\tcjso\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Android1_Test\app"  assemblex86-64Debug" exited with code 1.  Android1_Test   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V150\Android.Common.targets  546
```

We need a better answer as to what is wrong the this build related error. (Similar error on another part of StackOverflow but the answer is not very useful.)

Please advise.

Tim

I tried to run a Hello World app using Android emulator device.

I was expecting the Hello World text to show up in the emulated device attached to Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSB3073-The-command-gradlewbat--p-C:/10507303?page=16&pageSize=15&sort=active&topics=visual+studio+2019+version+16.0)?

Comment: No - thanks for telling me - looks like others are having the same issue.